# Regex for bit of the class of a div

Tags: regex

If I had a div in HTML that had class="blah user_foo", whats the Match() regex to get the 'foo' bit?

Comment: @givp: I'd accept Gumbo's answer instead of mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/<div\s(?:[^>'"]*|".*?"|'.*?')*?\bclass\s*=\s*"blah user_(.*?)"/i
```

The above handles whitespace; and other things before the class specification.

It doesn't handle the case where `class='single-quoted-something'`; you could do that with a backreference.  It also doesn't handle malformed HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If the `class` attribute is the only attribute of the wanted `div` elements and the `class` value always has the mentioned structure (fixed `blah` and then `user_`*`foobar`*), you could use this regular expression:

```
<div\s+class\s*=\s*"blah user_([^"\s]+)
```

Otherwise try this regular expression:

```
<div\s+(?:[^>"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*\bclass\s*=\s*"blah user_([^"\s]+)
```

The expression `(?:[^>"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*` also takes into account that a plain `>` is allowed as attribute value.

**Edit**    Optimized the regular expression with a look-ahead assertion to reduce backtracking:

```
<div\s+(?:(?:(?!class)[^>"']+(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')?)\s+)*class\s*=\s*"blah user_([^"\s]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which language uses Match(), but it will probably look something like this:

```
<div[^>]+class="blah user_([^"]+)"
```

Depending on the language, 'foo' may be stored in \1, or $1 or something else entirely.

Comment: Attribute values may contain plain `>` characters.

Comment: I see your point. Your solution does address this issue. I'll vote it up.